# How to move data from datagridview column to array then place data on another column after adding to it (windows forms .netframework)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Please help I have tried to move data from one datagridview column into an array in order to add (calculate) something from it and place it in another column called age. This is what I tried and wanted to see if the data is stored in an array but got a "use of unassigned local variable" error

```
    string data;
    int j = 3;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

         data = Convert.ToString(dgvData[j, i].Value);
            
    }
    MessageBox.Show(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable data may not have a value assigned to it in the for loop, which would cause the MessageBox to fail. This can be resolved by instantiating data with a default value.

```
    string data = "";
```

It looks like to me that you are also trying to display each value in the fourth column in the datagridview with MessageBox, so consider moving the MessageBox into the for loop. This could also allow you to move your data variable closer to the call, removing the need for the default value.

```
    int j = 3;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string data = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[j, i].Value);
        MessageBox.Show(data);
    }
```